# using Identity User to filter datarecords

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, authorization, database-connection

I have a database with company records. When a user logs in, he/she should only see those records for which he/she is authorized. I have implemented ASP.net MVC Identity and I have developed the database using Code First and Entity Framework.

It seems like a very straightforward programming task, but I am obviously overlooking something, as I cannot find a solution in the asp.net or msdn websites.

I am considering using a LINQ statement in the controller whereby I use an Where-statement to filter only those records where the Authenticated user (.GetUserID()) is equal to the Company UserId. Is this the proper way?

My CompanyController is very standard, as displayed hereunder

```
 public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? csearchid)
    {

        var viewModel = new CompanyIndexData();
        viewModel.Companies = db.Companies
          .OrderBy(i => i.CompanyName)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you was designing your application in multi tiers, you could abstract this for example with the Repository design pattern.

In your case you could use an extension method like :

```
public IQueryable<Company> ForUser(this IQueryable<Company> query, long userId)
{
    return query.Where(x => x.UserId == userId);
}
```

and use it in your controller :

```
public ActionResult Index(int? id, int? csearchid)
{

  var viewModel = new CompanyIndexData();
  viewModel.Companies = db.Companies.ForUser(this.GetUserId()).OrderBy(x => x.CompanyName);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks Gentiane, I will let you know if it will work for me.